(C, UDP Socket programming) My code doesn't work and I don't know why
I am making Server and Client using UDP socket programming
My Code's function is below

Server is sending image file to Client

multiThread

check bitsum to detect error


Transfer was successful, it's working.
But if the transfer was successful (bitsum is correct), the Client sends "success" to the Server.
Then, the Server breaks its infinite loop.
(like this)
printf("received message: %s\n", buffer);
if (!strcmp(buffer, "success"))
        {
            break;
        }

But it doesn't work.
The Server prints out success + binary file...
received message: successn;-�L=n��=�"��}�K+�#S�l����'A6=�MH�dC+ܐ�D�܏0)j��<YF�%0�;�j��'R�n
��W�|�l�6WL�.ʜ�ȫP��#�P��!<����2��PBB�9Cq5^�M`n�6D��Z��5HM�-

sbW&�����#iT���_ȝٶ�b�z�*l���d7vȆ�Cs��s�5�ڎɾɘfX�&�̘���/�C�":
                                                          �r4��d&��ۈ�yq�2�+6xѡt;A���%A*bI��5y�5AO?�ND�N��c\�2ƹ1��ف��nbI�JOcس\I��xVlic%�lr{Ѥ�!L��q�}����%ثF݉��ϧ��BT8D����0�؆���'��m[��H��#s��Hod�541��,��O��

I think buffer is success + some binary things so it can't break out the infinite loop.
I don't know where the code is wrong...
+ data transfer is successful but multisession doesn't work because of the problem which I described.
Entire Server.c  code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PORT 8888
#define BUF_SIZE 1254
#define MAX_CLIENTS 100

typedef struct
{
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int socket;
    int id;
} Client;

Client clients[MAX_CLIENTS];
pthread_t threads[MAX_CLIENTS];
int clientCount = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

unsigned short calculateChecksum(FILE *file)
{
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    unsigned short checksum = 0;
    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        checksum += (unsigned char)ch; 
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    return checksum;
}

void *handleClient(void *arg)
{
    int id = *((int *)arg);
    ssize_t bytesRead;

    // video file
    FILE *file;
    char *filename = "image.jpg";
    // open video file
    file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        perror("File opening failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    ssize_t bytes_read;
    // check file size
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t file_size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // define loop count
    size_t loopcount = file_size / BUF_SIZE;
    // what is the residue
    size_t residue = file_size % BUF_SIZE;
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    int i=0;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    strcpy(buffer,"retry");
    while (1)
    {   
        //problem 
        printf("received message: %s\n", buffer);
        if (!strcmp(buffer, "success"))
        {
            break;
        }
        else if(!strcmp(buffer, "retry"))
        {   printf("sending videofile\n");
            // data sending
            for (int i = 0; i < loopcount; i++)
            {

                size_t bytesread = fread(buffer, 1, BUF_SIZE, file);

                sendto(clients[id].socket, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&clients[id].address, sizeof(clients[id].address));
            }

            // residue data sending
            size_t bytesread = fread(buffer, 1, residue, file);
            sendto(clients[id].socket, buffer, residue, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&clients[id].address, sizeof(clients[id].address));

            printf("sending video file completed\n");
            char fileFinMessage[] = "fin";

            if (sendto(clients[id].socket, fileFinMessage, sizeof(fileFinMessage), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&clients[id].address, sizeof(clients[id].address)) < 0)
            {
                perror("sendto() failed");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            // sending checksum
            unsigned short checksum = calculateChecksum(file);
            sprintf(buffer, "%d", checksum);
            printf("checksum is %d \n", checksum);
            sendto(clients[id].socket, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&clients[id].address, sizeof(clients[id].address));

        }
        //is data transfer has not error?
        if(recvfrom(clients[id].socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, NULL, NULL)==-1){
            perror("recvfrom() failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int serv_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_adr;
    char message[BUF_SIZE];
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    socklen_t clnt_adr_sz = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    ssize_t str_len;

    // Create socket
    if ((serv_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // socket address
    memset(&serv_adr, 0, sizeof(serv_adr));
    serv_adr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_adr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_adr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // binding socket
    if (bind(serv_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_adr, sizeof(serv_adr)) == -1)
    {
        perror("bind() error");
        exit(1);
    }

    // mutex Init
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

    printf("waiting for client...\n");

    // Create a thraed for each client
    while (1)
    {
        // receive message from client
        str_len = recvfrom(serv_sock, message, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&clients[clientCount].address, &clnt_adr_sz);
        if (str_len < 0)
        {
            perror("recvfrom error");
            exit(1);
        }

        // print message
        message[str_len] = '\0';
        printf("client %d say: %s\n", clientCount + 1, message);

        // Add client to the list
        clients[clientCount].socket = serv_sock;
        clients[clientCount].id = clientCount;
        
        clientCount++;
        // send a message to the client
        sprintf(message, "hello i am server, you are Client %d\n", clientCount);
        if (sendto(clients[clientCount - 1].socket, message, strlen(message), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&clients[clientCount - 1].address, sizeof(clients[clientCount - 1].address)) < 0)
        {
            perror("sendto error");
            exit(1);
        }
        // create thread for client
        pthread_create(&threads[clientCount+1], NULL, handleClient, (void *)&clients[clientCount+1].id);
        pthread_join(threads[clientCount+1], NULL);
    }

    close(serv_sock);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    return 0;
}

Entire Client.c Code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1254
#define PORT 8888

unsigned short calculateChecksum(FILE *file)
{
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    unsigned short checksum = 0;
    int ch;

    while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        checksum += (unsigned char)ch; 
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    return checksum;
}

void fileRecive(int sock, struct sockaddr_in *serv_addr, socklen_t adr_sz)
{
    FILE *file = fopen("received_image.jpg", "wb");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        perror("File opening failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char message[BUFSIZE];
    size_t nbyte = BUFSIZE;
    while (1)
    {
        nbyte = recvfrom(sock, message, nbyte, 0, (struct sockaddr *)serv_addr, &adr_sz);
        if (!strcmp(message, "fin"))
        {
            printf("File received successfully.\n");
            break;
        }
        fwrite(message, nbyte, 1, file);
    }

    fclose(file);
}

int main()
{
    int sock;
    char message[BUFSIZE];
    int str_len;
    socklen_t adr_sz;

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, client_addr;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sock == -1)
    {
        printf("socket() error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    char hello_message[] = "hello i am client";
    sendto(sock, hello_message, strlen(hello_message), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    adr_sz = sizeof(client_addr);
    str_len = recvfrom(sock, message, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &adr_sz);

    message[str_len] = '\0';
    printf("Server say: %s\n", message);

    fileRecive(sock, &serv_addr, adr_sz);

    FILE *file2;
    char *filename = "received_image.jpg";
    
    if (file2 == NULL)
    {
        perror("File opening failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // checksum 검사
    recvfrom(sock, message, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &adr_sz);
    while (1)
    {   
        file2 = fopen(filename, "rb");
        printf("received checksum = %s\n", message);
        unsigned short checksum = calculateChecksum(file2);
        printf("calcualte checksum = %d\n", checksum);
        char checksumCheck[BUFSIZE];
        sprintf(checksumCheck, "%d", checksum);
        if (!strcmp(message, checksumCheck))
        {   
            printf("checksum correct\n");
            //problem
            sprintf(message, "success");
            printf("%s\n", message);
            sendto(sock, message, strlen(message), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
            fclose(file2);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("checksum incorrect");
            printf("\n");
            char retry_message[BUFSIZE] = "retry";
            sendto(sock, retry_message, strlen(retry_message), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
            fileRecive(sock, &serv_addr, adr_sz);
        }
    }

    close(sock);

    return 0;
}

I mark where is problem
This is Server's output
waiting for client...
client 1 say: hello i am client
received message: retry
sending videofile
sending video file completed
checksum is 7317
received message: successn;-�L=n��=�"��}�K+�#S�l����'A6=�MH�dC+ܐ�D�܏0)j��<YF�%0�;�j��'R�n
��W�|�l�6WL�.ʜ�ȫP��#�P��!<����2��PBB�9Cq5^�M`n�6D��Z��5HM�-

sbW&�����#iT���_ȝٶ�b�z�*l���d7vȆ�Cs��s�5�ڎɾɘfX�&�̘���/�C�":
                                                          �r4��d&��ۈ�yq�2�+6xѡt;A���%A*bI��5y�5AO?�ND�N��c\�2ƹ1��ف��nbI�JOcس\I��xVlic%�lr{Ѥ�!L��q�}����%ثF݉��ϧ��BT8D����0�؆���'��m[��H��#s��Hod�541��,��O��

Server.c didn't break out of the infinite loop because the Client sends the wrong message.
But I don't know why.
(I guess some algorithm issue).

You transfer raw binary data. You can't treat it as a string.

I know it,  but I don't know where is wrong...

The "wrong" is that you don't have a null-terminated string in buffer. It's something else. That means strcmp simply will not work, and instead you will have undefined behavior. As a workaround you can use strncmp to compare only the beginning of the string: strncmp(buffer, "success", 7).

Alternatively you could NUL-terminate the buffer before calling strcmp() on it, the same as you did 12 lines earlier in the same code:  str_len = recvfrom([...]); message[str_len] = '\0';
